# Не удаётся запустить проект asp.net core 2.2 MSB4018 RazorGenerate task failed unexpectedly DOTNET_HOST_PATH is not set

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Попробовал открыть проект asp.net core 2.2 после обновления VS2019 до новой версии с модным .NET 5 и прочими штуками.

Выдаёт ошибку при компиляции:

> MSB4018 RazorGenerate task failed unexpectedly DOTNET_HOST_PATH

Comment: модным C# **5**? =)

Comment: @ExplodingKitten лол ) вот что значит впопыхах писать текст.

Answer (score 0):

Помог [совет](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1224054/aspnet-core-22-framework-project-fails-to-build.html):

> Создать новую системную переменную в разделе Переменные среды
>
> Имя: DOTNET_HOST_PATH
>
> Значение: dotnet

И тоже не работают стили css :(

Похоже всё, легаси и пора окончательно перебираться в свежие тулчейны.